Synology DSM moved to new LAN can't access
I had my Synology DSM (version currently unknown) up and running in my old home. Then we moved, changed the provider, have a new router, etc. ...
Before my private network did run under 192.168.1., now with the new router it is 192.168.178. with 192.168.178.1 being my FritzBox router / DSL modem, etc. I have finally set up all the rest of my network, so changing the IP range back to the old one would be a nightmare.
When we moved in I managed to assign the IP address 192.168.178.2 to my Synology and could somehow access it. Currently I can't. In my Fritz Box network overview the address 192.168.178.2 is shown as in use and connected and with high probability this is my Synology since all addresses smaller than 192.168.178.20 are set as static.
If I do a ping I see the following:
PING 192.168.178.2 (192.168.178.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.178.23 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.178.23 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

If I try to reach the Synology via browser with 192.168.178.2:5000 I get host not reachable.
What can I do to access my Synology again?

I had to install the Synology Assistant and then reset the Synology appliance by holding the reset button with a pin for about 4 seconds.
The issue had been that the Synology was still using an IP from the old network setup, and resetting it was the only way to get it to use a new IP address. Once it had a valid IP from the new network I was able to access it in the Synology Assistant.

If your device is using DHCP/dynamic IP addresses, you usually just restart/"soft reset" the device in order to get it a new IP. If you manually set IP addresses for your devices, you will have to go into the device settings and update the addresses if your network settings change. Alternatively, you can make sure your new Router is set to use the same network configurations as the previous device.

After I finally got my printer to use the assigned fixed address and had defined a fixed IP range on the router I really wanted to avoid to do a complete new network setup. So the reset 1 was the easiest and also not painful solution to my problem, which didn't influence the rest of my network.
